# How can I automate some processes on my phone

Tags: stock-android, automation

I'm trying to figure out how to automate some processes on my phone:

1. when it rings I want to say "answer" or "pick up" and then be able to go converse with the caller through speakerphone.
2. would be the inverse: I want to say "call John Doe" then I want the call to be placed in speakerphone

For when I am driving:

1. when a text is received I want to say "read text" and my phone to read me the text message.
2. I want to say: "type text message to jon doe" then I want to dictate a message and my phone to type it and when I say send – it sends on a note

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not a big friend of it, but did you just describe *Google Now?* There are plenty of automation solutions around. Follow up to our [automation tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info), see my [Tasker collection](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker) (pay attention to *AutoVoice* & Co), or try any of the [personal assistants](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_personalassistants) available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Utter + Google Now. It can add tons more voice commands to Google Now, which can be activated while your phone is off just by saying "Okay Google".

http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2014/05/17/mastering-voice-control-android-going-beyond-google-now/

You can also try a different app called Commandr for Google Now.

Comment: Thank you all....these solutions are all excellent..will try them and see which best fits my needs..you guys rock. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a lot of automation apps that support speech recognition. But to listen for voice commands from the lock screen, will require the Google Now app, since it's the only app that be configured always listen. Some app examples:

- [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) - free, full/advanced automation
- [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) + AutoVoice - paid, full/advanced automation
- utter! - free, voice/simple automation
- Commander for Google Now - free, voice/simple automation